# Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 saving fails

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, save

when saving a source file e.g. .cs I often get the following

- Click Save, Save all or build (any action that triggers a save)
- VS prompts with a "Save As" dialog
- selecting the same filename as the original often fails with "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"

Waiting up to 30 seconds in the "Save As" phase normally results in success.

Things I've tried so far

1. disable Anti-virus - no effect
2. switch from local workspace (we use TFVC) to server workspace - problem goes away
3. modify the same files outside of VS - works without issue using Notepad / notepad ++
4. Disabling all addins / extension - no effect
5. Deleting workspace and recreating - problem less common initially then back to common
6. same source code for a dev that has not seen the issue - they don't see the issue
7. Running VS on a VM rather than our normal Workstations - same issue
8. upgrade TFS from 2013 to 2015 - same issue
9. Size of the workspace does not appear related.  Have seen the issue with small and large (>100k files)

These imply that the problem is workstation or user related.  Not related to source control. something to do with Visual studio

other info

- we don't use drive encryption
- source code drive is RAID 1 ssd
- VS saves files by creating a new temp file in the same directory then renaming it.  By monitoring the file system, i can see the temp file being created so it looks like the rename throwing the error.

there was a similar issue in MS connect which is marked as fixed:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/860265/unable-to-save-files-in-vs-2013-update-2-rc2

The error messages mentioned in the issue above appear to be different though,  create an existing file vs process is using file

This is affecting about 15 of 40 devs and the workaround is fairly distracting.  We have workarounds but would be good to know the cause

Comment: How many items are in your workspace? What's the size of your $tf folder? Local workspaces work up to a certain amount of data in the workspace. Creating a small scoped workspace that has just what you need to build is generally a good idea.

Comment: @jessehouwing: thanks, I've updated the description.  We tried big and small workspaces with the same results.  My current setup has 81k files in it.  $tf is 704MB with 54k files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this - a security product called Avecto.  Looks like an update that was deployed around January.

Removing Avecto makes the problem go away as a workaround.  Just disabling the Defendpoint service is not enough, it must be fully uninstalled.  Infra will no doubt raise a bug with our vendor.

It only affects files that live on an ssd, could not repro for files on hdd which is why not everyone was affected

Updated 2016-04-25: Avecto have a fix for this.  I'm not aware of the details (managed by another team) but we haven't had an issue since applying it.